# Reminding users to avoid copying text commend should link to a good explaination

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation, answers, comments

For example, [one of my answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/484/does-frequent-showering-change-the-amount-of-oils-our-skin-produces/1204#comment2333_1204) is considered to only contain quotes. At that time, the only reason given was "the super mod says so". In deed, in the link, the super mod only said so, not giving a specific reason. That had been irritating me because it is accepted in other sites.

Until today, when I read [his explaination](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/212/99):

> - It looks bad.
> - It offers little hope if the answer doesn't fully answer the question.
> - It leaves all the leg work of verification to the reader.

So I think we should refer to this link when leaving comment about this.