# Some moderators are too quick to delete comments

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I think overall, one or several moderators (I don't know who) tend to delete comments too quickly. In a few cases, some of my comments were deleted a few hours after I wrote them, then some reader asked me the same question as I was answering in the comments.

E.g. [Revisiting Research, A reason to close](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/515/43)

[image]

Could moderators please delete comments with less precipitation? Or even better, quit deleting comments that are relevant to the question. Thanks.

---

Comment deletion is much more frequent on this SE than the other one I frequent. I stopped writing answers as [they were deleted](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/what-to-do-when-a-question-is-precisely-answered-by-a-wikipedia-page-or-section), I'll do the same for comments.

Comment: This goes on to show that comments are not permanent and you should provide answers in an actual answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @JoeW You should provide answers in an actual answer instead of a comment.

Comment: FWIW, I was a little shocked that some of our comments were deleted, but I can understand how they were viewed as a conversation between two people (which I guess should have probably happened in chat).

Comment: @AtlLED - In my opinion, there should be more leeway for comments staying in meta - after all, this is the place where site decisions are made, so discussions happen. My post was mostly addressing the deletion of obsolete comments, which I think is appropriate. Half of a conversation makes no sense.

Answer (score 9):

[Comments are considered expendable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/262486) on *every* SE/SO site.

> Comments are disposable: unlike posts, there's no revision history, and they can be *deleted without warning* by their authors, by moderators, and in response to flags.

Flagging is an important form of community self-moderation, a highly regarded privilege on these sites. There are even badges awarded for helpful flags (often raised on comments.) Handling flags is one of the most important duties of moderators; it's one way to allow the community to participate in moderating and shaping their site.

If you make a comment in response to someone else (in effect having a conversation with that person, discouraged on SO sites), and the person you answered removes their comment, your comment immediately becomes *obsolete*, and if flagged by a user, the mod usually will delete the comment. This is true on every site I'm on. It's a very easy decision, since comments are not meant to be answers, are not equivalent to answers, and usually have no lasting value, *especially if the comment was part of a conversation half of which is now missing*. All it does is clutter the page, possibly confuse readers, and distract from the actual question or answer.

> Could moderators please delete comments with less precipitation? Or even better, quit deleting comments that are relevant to the question. Thanks.

I hope this is never the case, as it goes against the spirit of SO. If you want your words immortalized, write an answer. That's the model.

Comment: Comment deletion is much more frequent on this SE than the other one I frequent. I stopped writing answers as they were deleted, I'll do the same then for comments.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt why do you stop answering? Bad answers only get downvoted, not deleted.

Comment: @Ooker that is not true, My friend had an answer which got three upvotes before it was deleted by a moderator because "it didn't have good enough sources"... the funny thing is that the bureaucratic moderator who initially voted to close the answer also provided a competing answer with even less in the way of sources.... Interesting isn't it.